# AttributeError: 'CircularLinkedList' object has no attribute 'next'

Tags: python-3.x

I want to take use the list so that i can perform some manipulation on the data until my count becomes zero.But it is not letting me use the list passed to a function new list.Below is a code attached

```
 class Node:
    def __init__(self, data,count):
        self.data = data 
        self.count=count
        self.next = None


    class CircularLinkedList:
        def __init__(self):
            self.head = None 

  
    def append(self, data,count):
        if not self.head:
            self.head = Node(data,count)
            self.head.next = self.head
        else:
            new_node = Node(data,count)
            cur = self.head
            while cur.next != self.head:
                cur = cur.next
            cur.next = new_node
            new_node.next = self.head

    def print_list(self):
        cur = self.head 

        while cur:
            print(cur.data,cur.count)
            cur = cur.next
            if cur == self.head:
                break
    def newlist(list1):
        cur1=list1
        while cur1:
            print("hello")
            cur1=cur1.next
            if cur1==list1.head:
                break;
if __name__=='__main__':  
    list1 = CircularLinkedList()
    for i in range(0,len(name_p)):
        list1.append(name_p[i] ,5)
    list1.print_list()   
    newlist(list1)
```

Comment: AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-64dae591eb8e> in <module>()
     81         list1.append(name_p[i] ,5)
     82     list1.print_list()
---> 83 newlist(list1)
     84 
     

<ipython-input-24-41a9b864e6af> in newlist(list1)
     77 def newlist(list1):
     78     root1=list1
---> 79     while root1.next!=root1.head:
     80             print(hello)
     81             root1=root1.next
AttributeError: 'CircularLinkedList' object has no attribute 'next'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code might help you do what you want

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data,count):
            self.data = data 
            self.count=count
            self.next = None


class CircularLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None 

  
    def append(self, data,count):
        if not self.head:
            self.head = Node(data,count)
            self.head.next = self.head
        else:
            new_node = Node(data,count)
            cur = self.head
            while cur.next != self.head:
                cur = cur.next
            cur.next = new_node
            new_node.next = self.head

    def print_list(self):
        cur = self.head 

        while cur:
            print(cur.data,cur.count)
            cur = cur.next
            if cur == self.head:
                break
    def newlist(self,list1):
        cur1=self.head
        while cur1:
            print("hello")
            cur1=cur1.next
            if cur1==self.head:
                print('ho rha hai')
                break
if __name__=='__main__':  
    name_p='asada'
    list1 = CircularLinkedList()
    for i in range(0,len(name_p)):
            list1.append(name_p[i] ,5)
    list1.print_list()   
    list1.newlist(list1)
```